# BaggingRegressor (sklearn) with n_jobs having other than the default value results on an infinite loop

Tags: python, scikit-learn

When using other than the default value (*i.e.* 1) of **n_jobs** in sklearn **BaggingRegressor**, my computer (Intel Core i7-4600 CPU, 4 logical cores) enters an infinite loop (*e.g.* **n_jobs** = -1). With the default value, the execution time is milliseconds. What is the cause of this behavior? Thanks.

Comment: Try to pass `verbose=10` and check the output...

Comment: also, `n_jobs > 1` means it would probably fork your process, which means if your process has allocated a lot of memory, that memory would be allocated for each process (at least once you try to change those values, not sure when it actually duplicates the memory). This may take quite some time if the process is memory intensive.

Comment: With n_jobs = 1 and verbose = 10, the code runs smoothly and gives some reports (Building estimator 1 of 10 for this parallel run (total 10)...). When I assign n_jobs = 2 (and verbose = 10) and execute the code, it doesn't even start reporting (i.e. Building estimator 1 of 10...). The data is very simple ( x has 150 points and y = cos(x)). The process should not be memory intensive, as I am trying with some minimal parameters of the learner.